# How to open a dot file in M1 Mac using from command line using Cytoscape?

Tags: cytoscape.js, dot, cytoscape

How to open a dot file in M1 Mac using from command-line using Cytoscape.

Of course I can open Cytoscape.app manually and then load the dot file using GUI.

I am interested to know whether I can load the dot file directly from command-line given the path location to the dot file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the [dot-app](https://apps.cytoscape.org/apps/dotapp) installed, then it should be as simple as:

```
network import file file="path_to_file"
```